# Dynamic Constant Assignment error in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code:

```js
# calculates GST
def calculateGST(price)
GSTpaid = price * 0.15
return GSTpaid
end

puts "Enter a value: "
cost = gets.chomp.to_f

GSTpaid = calculateGST(cost)
costNoGST = cost - GSTpaid

puts """
Cost:         #{cost}
GST included: #{GSTpaid}
cost no GST:  #{costNoGST}
"""
```

This returns a dynamic constant assignment error on line 4.
I wrote the exact same program using python and it runs fine, so I'm curious to know why it doesn't work in Ruby??

While I'm at it, is there a way to insert Ruby code snippets into a post? I see options only for HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so I went ahead and used JS instead.

Comment: Normally, Snippets are for executable JavaScript (just like jsfiddle or jsbin), which can be run inside a browser. Running Ruby (or anything that is not JavaScript) is much harder. Normally, non-JS code will be formatted simply as code (four-space indent, or select and ctrl-K).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you are trying to make a constant, non-constant. Once it's been assigned you can't go back and change that. You could refactor this to use only local variables rather than constants:

```
def calculateGST(price)
  price * 0.15
end

puts "Enter a value: "
cost = gets.chomp.to_f

gst_paid = calculateGST(cost)
cost_no_gst = cost - gst_paid

puts """
Cost:         #{cost}
GST included: #{gst_paid}
cost no GST:  #{cost_no_gst}
"""
```

Comment: I understand why I get the error, but I'm confused as to why it works on python but not on ruby.

Comment: My Python isn't entirely up to scratch, but I believe it's because python doesn't really have 'constants' in the same way Ruby does. You can assign things with names of upper or lower case and it shouldn't make a difference. In Ruby, an upper case assignment indicates a constant, which you can't change once it has been assigned.

Comment: That's it ;) I didn't realize starting with an uppercase did that. Thanks for clearing this up!